# Unsupported expression: Non-overridable members (here: ) may not be used in setup / verification expressions

Tags: .net, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am using xUnit and Moq for writing test cases. I am using the code below to create a Mock but am getting the highlighted issue.

[image: Picture of code and error pasted below]

```
CloudBlockBlob source = null;
AccessCondition sourceAccessCondition = null;
AccessCondition destAccessCondition = null;
BlobRequestOptions options = null;
OperationContext operationContext = null;
CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(uri);
Task task = null;
DeleteSnapshotOption deleteSnapshotOption = new DeleteSnapshotOption();

var mockCloudBlobClient = new Mock<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient>();
mockCloudBlobClient.Setup(repo => repo.GetContainerReference("sample")).Returns(container);

var mockCloudBlobContainer = new Mock<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer>(uri);
mockCloudBlobContainer.Setup(repo => repo.GetBlockBlobReference("sample")).Returns(new CloudBlockBlob(uri));

var mockBlobServiceProvider = new Mock<BlobServiceProvider>();
mockBlobServiceProvider.Setup(repo => repo.GetBlockBlobContainer("sample")).Returns(new CloudBloblContainer(new Uri("http://mytest")));
```

The line `mockBlobServiceProvider.Setup(repo => repo.GetBlockBlobContainer("sample")).Returns(new CloudBloblContainer(new Uri("http://mytest")));` is giving me this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: repo => repo.GetBlockBlobContainer("sample")
>
> Non-overridable members (here: BlobServiceProvider.GetBlockBlobContainer) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'

Class `BlobServiceProvider`:

```
Public Class BlobServiceProvider
{
    public CloudBlobContainer GetBlockBlobContainer(string containerName)
    {
        CloudBlobContainer Container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        Container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        return Container;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The **`moq`** use [dynamic proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) to create wrapper around mocked type in order to be able to intercept calls and change the behaviour of the invoked methods.

How proxy is built?

- If you mocking `interface` proxy is just an implementation of the interface
- If you have `class` the proxy is override of the class

---

Question: Could you mock `sealed class` or non `virtual`(`abstract`) method?

You guess, no. There is no way to create wrapper around it using dynamic proxy. **`moq`** itself suggesting the same, if you look at the error:

> Non-overridable members (here:
>   BlobServiceProvider.GetBlockBlobContainer) may not be used in setup

---

To answer your question, either you need to extract the `interface` out of your provider and mock it or mark the method as virtual. Personaly, I do prefer option with the `interface` but it might requre some refactoring and DI.

Comment: While creating class, I have used Interface instead of class and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I had a class that implemented an interface and I accidentally mocked the class instead of the interface. I had:

```
var jfr = new Mock<JobFieldPropertyRetriever>();
```

instead of

```
var jfr = new Mock<IJobFieldPropertyRetriever>();
```